# Need help understanding attaching weapons to character

Tags: modeling, rigging

I have a character that has two swords. Both swords have a sheath. The sheaths and sword are separate objects. What I want is, I want the Sheaths to stay attached to the back of the character and the swords to stay in them as well.

I thought I'd have to attach the sheath and sword to my spine bone but that doesn't work as even the head can move them. They should only move with the body. So, when I go to animate him drawing his weapons, the sheaths shouldn't move and the sword should come right on out.

How would I go about doing this? If you also know of a video or article outlining this, please direct me there.

[image: Just a picture for visual context]

Comment: To animate him, you might just need to not attatch anything and just make the sheaths move manually.

Comment: if even the head can movethe sheath there's a problem here. As for being able to draw the sword from the sheath you could use the Child Of constraint, the sword would be first child of the sheath, then child of the hand, to make it easier you could use the Dynamic Parent addon, that will automatize the keyframes

Comment: @Jasper , ok you might be right. i could just animate the sheaths in the right spot.

Comment: @moonboots ok dynamic parent addon. Ill def look into that for sure. i know how to do the parent child thing. Just didnt know it was a constraint. I just started to get into constraints. So ill look into that. I should be able to figure this out soon. Just got off work ( 12 hours) so super late reply. Appreciate it. let me get on that now before i gotta get to sleep